# What are the Ubiquity logs on my Mac?

Tags: macos, logs

In the "~/Library/Logs" folder, I discovered a folder called "Ubiquity", but I have no such app named "ubiquity" on my MacBook Pro.

I Googled and also searched here (Ask Different), but all references to "ubiquity" seem to relate wifi or iCloud syncing, and my MBP has had issues with both, so I am curious what Ubiquity is.

FWIW: I began looking into the Logs folder because a message popped up to warn me of junk files that I should remove-by upgrading some software. There is indeed a huge number of files, but Ubiquity is the only name I didn't recognize and can't associate with any software.

Comment: Which version of macOS/OS X are you running on your MacBook Pro? Ubiquity does relate to iCloud syncing but it seems to just relate to older versions of macOS. What is the date on the newest file in that folder?

Comment: I am using Sierra (OS 10.12.6) and this is a newish laptop (2017)

Comment: To communicate with icloud resources MacOS/Cocoa has classes which store information on them.   This log tracks the external communication with the cloud service which is used by NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore in Foundation and other similar classes in CoreData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubiquity or Ubiquitous Data File is how iCloud shared documents get synced between your various devices and the cloud storage servers Apple runs. It’s a legitimate part of the macOS, but that doesn’t mean that the files you saw were legit as sometimes scam software like malware reuses a “safe” name to “hide in plain sight” so that someone would find my answer here or Apple’s documentation and conclude all is fine.

The most likely situation for you is all good, but we’d need to look at the detailed file to know for sure.